# Query de inserción de datos a través de una subconsulta. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Hola tengo una tabla de pedidos.

---

### Pedidos

- PedidoID
- UserID
- Articulos
- Precio
- created_at
- updated_at

Ahora cada pedido dependiendo de la cantidad de artículos genera una tarjeta de diferente en la cual se obtienen los datos de la persona a quien se le va a mandar el articulo.

---

### EnvioArticulos

- ArticuloID
- PedidoID
- Nombre
- Direccion
- created_at
- updated_at

Apartir de la tabla una y otra auxiliar tengo que meter los datos en la tabla de EnvioArticulos.

```
INSERT INTO EnvioArticulos (PedidoID, Nombre, Direccion)
      (SELECT a.PedidoID, b.Nombre, b.Direccion 
       FROM Pedidos a 
       INNER JOIN Datos b
       ON b.UserID = a.UserID)
```

El problema de esta inserción es que no hace una inserción por cada articulo si no la hace por cada pedido.

Necesito aplicar un ciclo **for de 0 a Pedidos.Articulos - 1** Pero no se como hacer esto en la base de datos.

Gracias por su ayuda Saludos.

Comment: Has validado While ? mira esta pagina (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: No lo he intentado. Crees que igual corra en Maria DB (MySQL) porque creo que la documentación del enlace es de SQL SERVE

Comment: (ttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/while.html) Revisa entonces este es la de MySQL

Comment: vale intentare usar el ciclo gracias.

Comment: A ver, si un pedido tiene 10 artículos, ¿lo que buscas es generar 10 filas en `EnvioArticulos`? Pero que pasa entonces con los datos de cada Articulo, ¿de dónde podrían salir? ¿Hay una tabla de `PedidoDetalle`?

Comment: Si es un cruce con otras dos tablas las cuales hacen referencia al UserID considere que resultaría mas enredado poner esas relaciones, en realidad la estructura de esta base de datos es una sopa. No se en que pensaban cuando la diseñaron.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes varios articulos por pedido, lo mejor seria tener una tabla que relacione los articulos con los pedidos:

Articulos:

- PedidoID
- ArticuloID
- ...

De manera que te quede:

```
INSERT INTO EnvioArticulos (PedidoID, Nombre, Direccion)
  (SELECT a.PedidoID, b.Nombre, b.Direccion 
   FROM Pedidos a 
   INNER JOIN Articulos c ON c.PedidoID = a.PedidoID
   INNER JOIN Datos b
   ON b.UserID = a.UserID)
```

De este modo tendrás un registro por cada articulo en el pedido

Comment: El sistema esta echo. Si quisiera normalizar la base de datos para corregir su estructura pero no puedo.

Comment: ¿Que tipo de dato es "Articulos" en la tabla de pedidos?

Comment: Es un entero (int 11)